# Why is my page wider than 100% and scrollable on the x-axis?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website on which I used to have `overflow: hidden;` activated the whole time (you scroll by using arrows). Now I got some bugs to fix and wanted to rework a few things, so to make it easier for me, I enable the scrollbar.

After this I saw that the page is wider than 100% (everything's set to `width: 100%;`.
The problem is, that this space shouldn't exist, even when I inspect the page and hover over the HTML and or body tags, they do not include that space beyond the 100%. (also not caused by margin/padding)

Obviously, I could just deny the scrollbar with `overflow-x: hidden;`, but I don't think that this is the right way to solve that issue. I'm thinking that some bugs could be caused by that problem.

When `overflow: hidden;` is active, the jQuery function `scrollTop()` also doesn't work anymore (Chrome), but on Edge it does.
This also seems a bit weird to me, since jQuery should manipulate the scrolling, even when hidden.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is it possible to post your site link here?

Comment: it would be great if you post your code here.

Comment: No one can answer this is you don't provide something for use to review. Please post your code.

Comment: I just thought that this would be some common bug. It's, as i already said, not caused by margin and or padding. You would be able to see this while inspecting the page..

Answer (score 0):

Even though I have no code or site to check if this is correct.

I have often found that you can have a div with 100% and also padding.

It's a nice idea to add box-sizing to your whole site so these additions are incorporated:

```
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *::before, *::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```